# Unity3D Same Matrix4x4 different eulers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, euler-angles

I have script that works with euler angles and it behaves differently on Windows PC and Android device.

I have the same Matrix4x4 as input but euler angles are not the same.

Test code:

```cs
var matrix = new Matrix4x4(
    new Vector4(-1, 0, 0, 0),
    new Vector4(0, 1, 0, 0),
    new Vector4(0, 0, 1, 0),
    new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1)
);

var eulers = matrix.rotation.eulerAngles;
```

The contents of eulers on Windows device are `(0, 180, -5.12263832E-05)` which I consider to be correct but on the Android device it's `(309.394653, 318.791473, 256.987244)`.

Which obviously messes up my code. Do you have any idea how to "normalize" these results so that both eulers would be the same?

The matrix is returned by `Tilemap.GetTransformMatrix(Vector3Int position)` and should represent orientation of a tile.

Comment: Note that there are [12 variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Conventions) of euler angles. There is no guarantee that any system uses the same convention as another, nor that the coordinate systems match. The documentation should specify coordinate systems and what euler angles are used.

Comment: It would help if you showed your code and explain what exactly is your usecase ... maybe using an entire Matrix just to get one Vector3 isn't the best way to go ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I wanted to do as @jfd348 gave me a hint.

> Your matrix is not a rotation matrix (in fact, it is a reflection about the YZ plane), so the very notion of Euler angles is not defined for it.

I used `var quat = Quaternion.LookRotation(matrix.GetColumn(2), matrix.GetColumn(1));`  to construct a quaternion that can be converted to eulers which represent correct rotation (or should i say orientation) on the 2D plane.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is not a rotation matrix (in fact, it is a reflection about the YZ plane), so the very notion of Euler angles is *not defined* for it. [The documentation for `Matrix4x4.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4-rotation.html) does not specify any behaviour when the matrix is not a rotation matrix, so you should assume that it can return *anything*, even different values on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67914173/7111561) also see [`Quaternion.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html)

> When you read the `.eulerAngles` property, Unity converts the `Quaternion`'s internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. **Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned.**

Which representation exactly is chosen when might vary for just a tiny little shift due to floating point imprecision.

=> Fazit: Try to avoid working with Euler angles as much as possible.

---

However, the values you are getting seem to be oddly off by far!

They are not a matter of different representations of the (approximately) same rotational `Quaternion` value but they are completely different rotations! I doubt very much that Unity would suddenly interpret the same `Matrix4x4` completely different on another platform

-> It rather seems you don't show us the actual entire use case.